# Baggage check-in rules for Lufthansa airlines

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, lufthansa, check-in

I am travelling from Mumbai to Lafayette via Munich-Houston by Lufthansa. Do I need to claim my checked luggage to clear customs in Munich and Houston?

Comment: I'm almost certain you need to for Houston, but I'm not sure about Munich. Are you staying in the airport ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that when traveling on one ticket you do not need to get your luggage in Munich, unless you have a long layover like 24 hours.

Comment: This is really two distinct questions, with two separate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know from your other question that you're on a single booking, so...

You won't claim baggage in Munich; it's just a normal international transit. You sit in the airport for a few hours until your next plane is ready to take you to Houston.

In Houston, like everywhere else in the US, international arrivals have to carry their checked baggage through Customs. You'll clear passport control, go down the escalator to baggage claim, get your bags, and take them through Customs. Immediately past Customs are airline counters where you can re-check your baggage. Conveniently these are also next to the escalators back up, which you'll use to take the TerminalLink train to Terminal B to catch your next flight.